# How to connect Soap Wsdl/Rest Url in IBM mobile first platform 8.0?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

As per my [knowledge](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/adapters/developing-adapters/) adapters are created to connect Soap WSDL or Rest URL.The documentation says how to create Adapters in IBM mobile First,but I want to know how to connect to Soap WSDL and Rest URL through Adapters.

Can anyone help me?

I have:

- Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
- Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)
- Build id: 20160218-0600
- Windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the link you have mentioned, you will find the section "Tutorials to follow next".

Specific to your query, you should review how this is done in Javascript or Java adapters at the following links:

1. [Javascript](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/adapters/javascript-adapters/js-http-adapter/)
2. [Java](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/adapters/java-adapters/java-http-adapter/)

Comment: Thanks a lot Vivin. Can you please help to integrate the created application with the adapter?

Comment: @Janaki, you will find information on integration in the "ResourceRequest" tutorials. There are working samples as well in there - for hybrid and native